# What does pinboard mean?

Tags: meaning

I couldn't find anything in Longman dictionary about this word, but I heard it somewhere which by now I don't remember where and when.
What does it mean?

Comment: see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinboard There are also other contexts where it is used as a technical term, see: http://www.dcache.org/manuals/Book-1.9.5/reference/rf-glossary.shtml and similar other uses.

Comment: And then there's [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinboard&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&biw=1280&bih=605)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a board made of cork or similar material to which notices can be pinned.

Comment: Is it British or American?

Comment: @webdesigner: It’s used in Britain, but the earliest recorded use is in the ‘Washington Post’. There is, incidentally, another meaning. It can also be, I now discover, ‘a panel having an array of identical sockets each connected to some of a set of wires, so that inserting a conducting pin into any of the sockets makes an electrical connection between a specific pair or group of wires’ (OED).

Comment: Most people in the US would call this a bulletin board.

Comment: @Barrie England What do you mean with used in Britain, that other countries don't have pinboards ?About the newly discovered second meaning - is that the old-fashioned board in the movies when they put you through, when the operators usually females make telephone connection?

Comment: @speedyGonzales: I mean that even though it's used in Britain, it first appeared in the United States. No, it doesn't sound like a telephone exchange.

Comment: @speedyGonzales - In the "wiring panel" case, the terms *plugboard* and *control panel* are more commonly used than is *pinboard*.  Photos: wired-up [panel](http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/witexhibit/wit_definitions.html), panel [in place](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/407.html) (see second and third photos).